# Reading from an infinitely running program using python subprocesses

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess

I am relatively new to python and I wanted to work on subprocesses. 
I want to run a python program in one terminal and show the output in the other terminal line by line while it is being executed in the other terminal. 
I have created an infinite for loop. as the first program.

Here's my second program to get the output. I am using subprocess in python, but I don't get the real time output coz the the second program only executes after the first program is done with its execution.

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep
import sys
# run the shell as a subprocess:
p = subprocess.Popen(['python','/Users/salauddinali/Desktop/temp.py'],stdout = subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)
# let the shell output the result:
sleep(0.1)
for c in p.stdout.read():
        n = c.decode('UTF-8') 
        print (n)
```

Comment: Replace `.read()` with `.readlines()`, and I think this will work.  `.read()` with no parameter tries to read *everything* (and then you loop over the characters of that string, and print them individually).

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper.
It did work with readlines, you were right. 
So, based on what I have found out - The subprocess does not work well with sleep(). The other program which the subprocess was from had sleep in it. (the indefinite for loop had a 2 second sleep before printing.) 
The subprocess did not like that, it it displayed nothing. Once I removed the sleep and used readline, it practically ran the script in the second terminal. 

However, I was stuck with the bufsize parameter, I don't know how that works yet. 
If you know anything about bufsize, do elucidate. 
Have a good day.

Comment: The `sleep()` issue _could_ be due to Python buffering the output when run as a subprocess not directly connected to a shell. If so, it should work if you add the option `-u` for unbuffered in your call to (the subprocess) Python interpreter. Thus, you need to modify your `Popen` call slightly to `p = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-u', '/Users/salauddinali/Desktop/temp.py'],stdout = subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)`. But then again, you have already reduced the buffer size so I don't know if it will help.